# No Read-Write on Samba Share

Tags: samba

I’m unable to edit files on a Samba share.

I’ve got two machines, srv001 and desk001, both with Arch Linux.  I want to connect to srv001 from desk001 using samba and sshfs (different scenarios), but I installed them a little differently, resulting in the users having different UIDs/GIDs (see below).

srv001 - Users:

- UserA [1000], primary group ‘mediaPublic [1002]’
- ServerA [1001], primary group ‘mediaPublic [1002]’

desk001 – Users:

- UserA [1001], primary group ‘mediaPublic [1001]’
- ServerA [1000], primary group ‘mediaPublic [1001]’

Most of the served files on my server belong to ServerA:mediaPublic, both users UserA and ServerA belong to group mediaPublic.   They have a Samba entry:

```
[media_public] 
comment = Media Server Centre - Media Files 
read only = no 
locking = yes 
path = /mnt/local/media/public
guest ok = no 
write list = UserA, ServerA

force create mode = 2770 
force directory mode = 2770 
force user = msc 
force group = mediaPublic
```

...and an /etc/fstab entry:

```
//srv001/media_public /mnt/remote/srv001/public cifs vers=2.1,uid=1000,gid=1001,username=UserA,password=APassword 0 0
```

Before Mounting:

```
[root@desk001 srv001]# ls -l
total 4K
drwxrwxr-x 2 ServerA media_public 4K May 24 19:35 public
```

After Mounting

```
[root@desk001 srv001]$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 ServerA media_public 0K May 27 17:30 public
```

After Mounting - Public Subfolder

```
[root@desk001 srv001]# ls /mnt/remote/srv001/public/ -l --block-size=M
total 527M 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ServerA media_public 523M Oct  6  2017  
archlinux-2017.10.01-x86_64.iso
drwxr-xr-x 2 ServerA mediaPublic         1M Jan 19  2017  Images
drwxr-xr-x 2 ServerA mediaPublic         1M May 25 09:41  Torrents
drwxr-xr-x 2 ServerA mediaPublic         1M May 24 22:19  TVShows
drwxr-xr-x 2 ServerA mediaPublic         1M Dec 20 12:12  Wallpapers
```

srv001

```
root@msc001x: /mnt/local/int001/MEDIA$ ls -l --block-size=K
total 104032K
drwxrws---+ 1 ServerA mediaPublic      1K Dec 16 22:07 Personal
-rwxrws---  1 ServerA mediaPublic 104032K May 30  2017 plexmediaserver_1.7.2.3878-8088811b8_amd64.deb
drwxrwsr-x+ 1 ServerA mediaPublic      1K May 27 17:30 Public
```

srv001 - public sub folder

```
root@srv001:/mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Public$ ls -l --block-size=M
total 527M
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ServerA mediaPublic 523M Oct  6  2017 archlinux-2017.10.01-x86_64.iso
drwxrwsr-x+ 1 ServerA mediaPublic       1M Jan 19  2017 Images
drwxrwsr-x+ 1 ServerA mediaPublic       1M May 25 09:41 Torrents
drwxrwsr-x+ 1 ServerA mediaPublic        1M May 24 22:19 TVShows
drwxrwsr-x+ 1 ServerA mediaPublic        1M Dec 20 12:12 Wallpapers
```

What is my problem.  Firstly how, with the above Samba scenario, can I map the users so I can access the files as the correct user.  Secondly, why is it mounting as 755 when it was originally 775 before mount.,

Comment: Unlike `NFS`, the `uid` and `gid` don't need to be the same with `smb`. Did you set an `smb password` for `UserA` and `ServerA` on `srv001`? Are you using those to connect to the share?

Comment: @NasirRiley I am, I just changed it to a credential file and it acts the same way.  Starts as 775 before mounting (mount point and remote directory), becomes 755 after mounting.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `ls -l` on the share before and after it's mounted.

Comment: I've added the ls -l as requested./

Comment: Your `fstab` is mounting the share in `/mnt/remote/srv001/public`. Go into `public` and run `ls -l` to show the ownership and permissions. Also, does `srv001` also contain a directory called `www` and what are the contents of the `media_public` directory on the share?

Comment: msc001x contains a folder 'public' which is mapped to the samba share 'media_public'.  srv001 contains public and www, both of which are samba shares.  Contents are in the ls I've added.  Everything at/below public or www is only editable by the owner (ServerA), above this it is editable by the owner (ServerA) and group (mediaPublic).  So why does the group lose rw at/below this level.  I've corrected the group/samba share name, mediaPublic is group. media_public is the share.

Comment: Please run the commands on the same machine where it isn't working. It's difficult to follow when you show the first `ls -l` on `desk001` and the second `ls -l` on an entirely different machine called `asystemoverload` where it's mounted in an entirely different location. Also, show what the permissions for the share on the server itself because what you're showing are the permissions on the client directory. It's important to know what the permissions are on the server side itself.

Comment: Apologies, I'd been sanitising the server and user/group names and missed one.  I've tidied it and added the server listings from the server.  note it has full 775, except the group is 'rws' rather than 'rwx'.  So why is it losing the groups 'write' when it is mounted.  I've run a test with a new user/group and directory and it does exactly the same, goes from 775 to 755. :(

Comment: I'm still rather confused here. Your `fstab` says that the mountpoint on `desk001` is `/mnt/remote/srv001/public` but then you run `ls -l` on `/mnt/remote/msc001x/public/` which is a different directory. The directories on `Srv001` show that the directories have sizes greater than zero and there is also a file called `archlinux-2017.10.01-x86_64.iso` whereas the directories on `desk001` have sizes of `0` and `archlinux-2017.10.01-x86_64.iso` is nowhere to be found. Also, what is `/mnt/local/int001/MEDIA/Public$` under `Srv001 - same folder`? I thought that the share was `media_public`?

Comment: Sorry, we'll get there eventually. Not sure why it had zero for the directories, I had removed some files/folders. I've updated the sizes.  Also added the folder above public for a complete picture.